# JQuery Validation Engine: detaching validation dynamically to a chosen field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

i was developing a registration form and i have attached Jquery's validation engine to it.

I have read the docs on https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine but i still did not find a way to detach the Validation check to a specific input box.

I have seen that there's info about how to group together a selected number of input and/or check boxes for the validation, but haven't found a way to set the group for a validation-detaching purpose.

I'd like to dynamically set some input boxes free from the validation check without having to hide them from the form.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all classes ....

```
 $("#InputsYouDontNeedValidationOn").removeClass();
```

Then the validation wont be run ...

Answer (score 0):

I use CSS class names to defined validation rules.

Then I use jQuery `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to dynamically adjust rules.

Sometimes, it helps run `$(":input").valid()` to clear out error messages that don't apply anymore after changing validation rules.